# Simple Javascript loop that repeats each second

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a code to move a character in a browser game. I managed to get the pixels it must move per second both horizontally and vertically.

pxsecx is the number of pixels it must move horizontally per second
pxsecy is the same but vertically

Basically it should += them to the current horizontal and vertical position.

I need the loop to keep repeating itself every second until the element position meets the new position (newx).

This is as far as I have gone:

```
<body onmousedown="showCoords(event)">
<script type="text/javascript">
function showCoords(evt){
  oldx = parseInt(document.getElementById("character").style.left);
  oldy = parseInt(document.getElementById("character").style.top);

  width = parseInt(document.getElementById("character").style.width);
  height = parseInt(document.getElementById("character").style.height);

  newx = evt.pageX - width/2;
  newy = evt.pageY - height/2;

  disx = newx - oldx;
  disy = newy - oldy;

  diag = parseInt(Math.sqrt(disx*disx + disy*disy));

  speed = 50;

  secs = diag/speed;

  pxsecx = disx/secs;
  pxsecy = disy/secs;

     while(document.getElementById("character").style.left<newx)
      {
      document.getElementById("character").style.left += pxsecx;
      document.getElementById("character").style.top += pxsecy;
      }
}
</script>
```

Everything works until the while where I have no idea how to do make it work every second. I'm testing it here: http://chusmix.com/game/movechar.php

How do I make it repeat that once a second so it works?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JavaScript is primarily asynchronous, so you'll need to rewrite this a little. `setTimeout` executes a function after a certain amount of time. Therefore, you can do this:

```
(function move() {
    var character=document.getElementById("character");
    if(character.style.left<newx) {
        character.style.left += pxsecx;
        character.style.top += pxsecy;
        setTimeout(move, 1000);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please tell me how to include it into my script. I tried but I'm awful at javascript. Could you just paste the final code? I don't know how to include it on it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Just replace your current `while` loop with it.

Comment: Does it matter that the values you're comparing in your if statement aren't the same type.  `if("100px" < 432)` seems to always return false.  This doesn't appear to be working code although it's close. Can you double check? I think once your types are the same this will work, but not in this current format.

Comment: @jmort253: If they were both numbers but one was in a string, it would work. It's just the `"px"` that's making it fail to be recognized as a number. I realized this wouldn't quite work when I posted it, but neither did the OP's original code; I thought this was merely pseudocode and they would add in different variables or correct parsing of the numbers later.

Comment: Great answer. +1.  I actually spent enough time working with what you posted to know that it will work if the OP handles the "px" stripping part.  Since he accepted your answer, I'm assuming he did indeed figure it out :)

Answer (score 14):

You can use the function `setInterval(function, interval)`

```
// To start the loop
var mainLoopId = setInterval(function(){
    // Do your update stuff...
    move();
}, 40);

// To stop the loop
clearInterval(mainLoopId);`
```

Comment: The interval (shown by 40 in this example), represents milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

to loop something every second you'll have to use a set interval:

```
let before = new Date();

setInterval(() => {
    console.log(Math.round((new Date() - before) / 1000));
}, 1000);
```

this code gets the date of the run and is subtracted to the date of every second. (by the way it starts at one not at zero, so you will have to do it manually if you want)

Answer (score 0):

I made a coffescript class to handle time loops, maybe it will be helpful for someone.

```
# Classe TimeLoop, execute a function every x miliseconds
#
# @example How o create a loop
#   myLoop = new TimeLoop((-> alert("loop"),1000)
#   myLoop.start()
#
class window.TimeLoop
  constructor: (@function,@miliseconds) ->

  # Start loop.
  #
  start: -> @loop = setInterval @function, @miliseconds

  # Stop loop.
  #
  stop: -> clearInterval(@loop)
```

link to gist: https://gist.github.com/germanotm/6ee68f804860e2e77df0

Answer (score -1):

You want the JavaScript `setTimeout()` function.  It calls a function every n milliseconds.

Comment: Milliseconds, not microseconds.

Comment: While you can use setTimeout to accomplish that coding a little, you must look for setInterval wich does it for you.

Comment: This is false. `setTimeout` invokes a function *one time only*. To invoke repeatedly, use `setInterval`.